# jQuery populate an input field and summernote

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I need to populate an input field and a summernote altogether, but showing different text on the input and on the summernote.

I was able to do the population using jQuery and assigning a specific function to different button links, so for example BTNLINK-1 will show text AAA in SUBJECT and AABB in the Summernote field, BTNLINK-2 will show text BBB in SUBJECT and BBCC in the Summernote and so on. Below is a sample code how I did that:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Template</label><br>
<a class="btn btn-default" id="btn1">Template1</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="btn2">Template2</a>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="subject">SUBJECT:</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Write your subject" required/>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea class="input-block-level summernote-modal"  id="textfield" name="message"></textarea>
</div>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#subject").val("AAA");
    $(".summernote-modal").summernote('code', '<p>AABB</p>');
});
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#subject").val("BBB");
    $(".summernote-modal").summernote('code', '<p>BBCC</p>');
});
}
```

Now the buttons have become 8 and we're planning to add more, so this solution takes a lot of space in the form.
Can you please help me to convert from links to a dropdown list, so when I select an item from the list, it will automatically update the input field and the Summernote field?

I tried already some options available on Stackoverflow where I could populate the value of input field but not Summernote field which remained always blank.

I understand that I should add some variables for each case on select of dropdown, I'm just stuck...

Thanks

Comment: So you should add a dropdown to your html and the change to your javascript from using `<a>` to using `<select>` would be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it this way, hope this helps someone else in the future:

I have a select box

```
<select id="template" class="chosen-select">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <optgroup label="English">
            <option value="1">Welcome1</option>
            <option value="2">Welcome2</option>
            <option value="3">Welcome3</option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

The JavaScript will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[id="template"]').change(function(){
        if ($("#template").val() == "")
            {
                $("#subject").val("");
                $(".summernote-modal").summernote('code', '');
            }
        if ($("#template").val() == "1")
            {
                $("#subject").val("Welcome1 subject");
                $(".summernote-modal").summernote('code', '<p>Welcome 1 text</p>');
            }
        if ($("#template").val() == "2")
            {
                $("#subject").val("Welcome2 subject");
                $(".summernote-modal").summernote('code', '<p>Welcome2 text</p>');
            }
        if ($("#template").val() == "3")
            {
                $("#subject").val("Welcome3 subject");
                $(".summernote-modal").summernote('code', '<p>Welcome3 text</p>');
            }
});
});
</script>
```

So depending on what user selects from the dropdown list, two fields contects change, where one of the fields is a Summernote

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had a select box with id attribute = "yourSelect", and you wanted to populate both the text field and the RTE field with the same "value" of the selected option:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#yourSelect").change(function(){
    $("#subject").val($(this).val());
    $(".summernote-modal").summernote('code', '<p>' + $(this).val() + '</p>');
});
}
```

Comment: Actually for each selection I must show a different text for the #subject and different text for .summernote-modal

Comment: Where are those going to come from?  Options have a value and a displayed value, so in theory there are two places, but you can't see the value when you're using the dropdown, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

function GetUserDetails(id){
$('hidden_blog_id').val(id);

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url('Crud/Updatecontent');?>",{
    id:id
}, function(data,status){
    var user = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#blogtitle').val(user.title);
    $('#my_image').attr('src',user.image_path);
    $('#blogimagepath').html(user.image_path);
    $('#blogstatus').val(user.status);
    $('#blogshortdesc').summernote('code',user.short_desc);
    $('#blogextradesc').summernote('code',user.extra_desc);
}
    );
    $('#update_blog_model').modal('show');
```

}